# No environment variable set after installation of MSI generated by WIX

Tags: wix, environment-variables

My WSX file looks like this: https://gist.github.com/pyeremenko/891eceb779197e4be240#file-sample-wxs-L23-L25

Copying works fine, i.e. exe file available in `Program Files/test/my_test` folder, but I can't access `TEST` env variable after installation via `echo %test%` (of course I reload cmd)

I tried also to look for it in System Properties > Environment Variables, but there is no such var there

What should I do to make MSI register env variable?

Comment: Here's an example: http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/03/28/from-msi-to-wix-part-13-installable-items-environment-variable.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the above WSX file with WIX 3.9 produces these errors:

```
Product.wxs(23,0): error LGHT0204: ICE18: KeyPath for Component: 'EnvVariable' is Directory: 'INSTALLDIR'. The Directory/Component pair must be listed in the CreateFolders table.
Product.wxs(23,0): error LGHT0204: ICE21: Component: 'EnvVariable' does not belong to any Feature.
```

To get installed, the component `EnvVariable` needs to be associated with a feature.  Try combining `<Environment...>` with `<File...>` into a single component:

```
    <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='77777777-8888-4fb0-892f-d62579f11b8d'>
       <File Id='my_testexe' Name='hello.exe' DiskId='1' Source='D:\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SetupProject1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe' KeyPath='yes' />
       <Environment Id='UpdateTest' Name='TEST' Action='set' Permanent='yes' System='yes' Part='all' Value='TestTestTest' />
    </Component>
```

Remove the now empty component `<Component Id='EnvVariable'...>`.

If you still have problems, you could try running the installer with diagnostic logging:

```
msiexec /l*v Install.log /i InstallPackage.msi
```

Search the file `Install.log` for **MainExecutable** to see how the component is being installed.